# Picking file path and file name with async file download

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

I am currently using this code (python 3.5.2):

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

urls = ["link"]
result = Pool(4).map(urlretrieve, urls)
print(result[0][0])
```

It works, but gets saved to the temp file with some weird name, is there a way to pick a file path and possibly a file name? as well as adding a file extension, it gets saved without one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to supply a location to `urlretrieve`. However `pool.map` doesn't appear to support multiple args in functions ([Python multiprocessing pool.map for multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments)). So, you can refactor, as described there, or use a different multiprocessing primitive, e.g. `Process`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

urls = ["link", "otherlink"]
filenames = ["{}.html".format(i) for i in urls]
args = zip(urls, filenames)
for arg in args:
    p = Process(urlretrieve, arg)
    p.start()
```

In the comments you say you only need to download 1 url. In that case it is very easy:

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
urlretrieve("https://yahoo.com", "where_to_save.html")
```

Then the file will be saved in `where_to_save.html`. You can of course provide a full path there, e.g. `/where/exactly/to/save.html`.

Comment: I did get a     raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: f>

Comment: Actually i was getting errors too.I thought that would have worked. See edit.

Comment: The core of your issue is that you need to pass a filename to `urlretrieve`.

Comment: i only need to download 1 url at a time. currently i get this exception AssertionError: group argument must be None for now

Comment: @Jellybean if you only need to download one url, then you don't need to use `Pool`.